# *ngFor in Angular 4 returns the following error on .shift(): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroyed' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

When I remove the first element in my array of objects, I receive the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroyed' of null.

Where is this coming from?

---

My html page:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let s of this.lastScores">
        <ion-label>
            <ion-grid>
                <ion-row >
                    <ion-col size="3">
                        {{s.score}}
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col size="3">
                        {{s.totalScore}}
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col size="6">
                        <small>{{s.newText}}</small>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

I add items to the front as follows:

```
this.lastScores.unshift({
    'score':      1,
    'newText':    'hello',
    'totalScore': 10,
})
```

And delete them as follows:

```
this.lastScores.shift();
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

I use `this.ref.detectChanges()` from the constructor `private ref: ChangeDetectorRef` as the function is called after a .subscribe and need to update the DOM.

Comment: If you use splice you instead of shift do you still get an error?.
also maybe if you use the spread syntex to reassign the array you wouldn't need to do menual change detaction like: this.lastScores = [newvalue, ...this.lastScores]

Comment: Yes same error again. detectChanges I still need for the splice right?

Comment: you dont need chnge detaction if you reassing the variable of the array, and i'm pretty sure that there is not need of menual change detaction when splicing.
maybe the problem is actually with the change detaction because i have no any idea other than that

Comment: Well if I dont call change detection the array is not updated in the DOM. I am using it within a function .subscribe()

Comment: try to add with spread and remove with splice or reassining the array with filter, or split, and avoid the menual change detaction, maybe it will work

Comment: Without the change detection the view is not updated, but then indeed there are no errors.

Comment: What is even weirder, when I just delete the array or set it to [], then there is no problem or need for a detectChanges. It is just the splice that is acting weird.

Comment: have you tried using a temp array and then just assign it's value to lastScores array?

Comment: @itdoesntwork No, can you elaborate where to put the temp array and how and where to assign/update it?

Comment: Have you found a solution for your issue? Having the same right now.

Answer (score -1):

just use  angular slice pipe
< *ngFor="let s of lastScores | slice : 0  : 1 " }}

Comment: What does that exactly do?

Comment: use slice pipe for remove object in array follw this link  https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Comment: I do not want to remove anything in the for loop. This is not the question